# Box shadow right side is falling out of its container

Tags: html, css

I have used the following CSS to give my container some box shadow:

```
.universal-wrapper{ 
    max-width: 1170px;
    margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
.universal-wrapper:before {
    box-shadow: -15px 0 15px -15px inset;
    content: " ";
    height: 100%;
    left: -15px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.universal-wrapper:after {
    box-shadow: 15px 0 15px -15px inset;
    content: " ";
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: -15px;
    width: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

However, [as you can see](http://mypropainters.com/vcdev/), the right side is falling outside of the container. Any idea how to resolve this?

What I've done so far:

- Floated the absolutely-positioned pseudo elements and it didn't help.

Comment: would be nice if you provide a snippet instead of a link to the site: now your question is difficult to follow for somebody looking for a similar issues and solutions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to absolutely position the `:after` pseudo element at the top, therefore you need to add `top:0`. In doing so, the pseudo element is absolutely positioned at the top, relative to the parent element, `.universal-wrapper`.

```
.universal-wrapper:after {
    box-shadow: 15px 0 15px -15px inset;
    content: " ";
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: -15px;
    width: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 0;
}
```

Tested in the developer tool, it works.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

You could just give your "universal-wrapper" a box shadow (or 2 if you're into that kind of thing)

```
.universal-wrapper {
    box-shadow: 15px 0 15px -8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), 15px 0 15px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

Something like that.